# xcodebuild not finding gcc 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I am trying to run xcodebuild and I am getting the following error:

```
2011-12-11 04:42:22.834 xcodebuild[9155:4203] error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1" UserInfo=0x4001a61a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1, NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such file or directory}
2011-12-11 04:42:22.835 xcodebuild[9155:4203] Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'gcc-4.2' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'objective-c'.
Compiler: /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2
Reason:   /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1
2011-12-11 04:42:22.895 xcodebuild[9155:4203] error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1" UserInfo=0x4013cbb80 {NSLocalizedDescription=Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1, NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such file or directory}
2011-12-11 04:42:22.900 xcodebuild[9155:4203] Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'gcc-4.2' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'c'.
Compiler: /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2
Reason:   /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1
```

Any idea why this is? I am guessing that it is because I don't have gcc-4.2 in the following path:

```
/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2
```

as of right now gcc-4.2 is located at usr/bin. The question is how do I redirect it?

Answer (score 1):

This could be be related to your $CC variable in your shell ( it keeps track of your compiler ) you can find more information [from jMoody on github](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/issues/74#issuecomment-3282274)

Essentially you need to remove $CC

Answer (score 0):

How did you select the compiler? Go to the Xcode navigator, click on the upmost item, then in the right window on your project (not the target), then `Build Settings`. U and in the section `Build Options` you can select the compiler. Usually you can choose between LLVM gcc-4.x and some Apple LLVM x.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `xcode-select` to select the version of Xcode you want to use?

[Manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html).